# Basic loop with sympy gives me this error message : 'Symbol' object is not subscriptable

Tags: loops, matrix, sympy

```
H = Matrix([[J[0,:],J[1,:],J[2,:]]])
```

I want to create a loop within sympy, so i don't need to input manually 0,1,2, etc..
with J being a symbolic matrix

Here's my code:

```py
from sympy import *
def make_Aij(m, n, a='a') :
    from sympy import Symbol, Matrix # just in case they aren't already loaded
    A = zeros(m, n)
    for i in range(0, m) :
        for j in range(0, n) :
            s = a+'_'+str(i)+str(j)
            exec  (s + "= Symbol('" + s + "')") # go look up what "exec" does!
            exec ("A[i, j] = " + s)
    return A
C = make_Aij(5, 5, 'c')
tri_upper_no_diag = np.triu(C, k=1)
J = Matrix(tri_upper_no_diag)
J

Z = zeros(5,5)

i = 0
while i < 1:
    J[:,i] = Z[:,i]
    J[i,:] = Z[i,:]
    i = i + 1
J

i = 1
T = ('J[0,:]')
while i < 5:
    s = (",J[i,:]")
    T = T + s
    i = i + 1
    
    d = Matrix([[T]])
d
```

Error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-0220d335bd1c> in <module>
      6     i = i + 1
      7 
----> 8     d = Matrix([[T]])
      9 d
     10 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\matrices\dense.py in __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    294 
    295     def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
--> 296         return cls._new(*args, **kwargs)
    297 
    298     @classmethod

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\matrices\dense.py in _new(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    306             rows, cols, flat_list = args
    307         else:
--> 308             rows, cols, flat_list = cls._handle_creation_inputs(*args, **kwargs)
    309             flat_list = list(flat_list) # create a shallow copy
    310         self = object.__new__(cls)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\matrices\matrices.py in _handle_creation_inputs(cls, *args, **kwargs)
   1087                             else:
   1088                                 c = len(row)
-> 1089                                 flat = [cls._sympify(i) for i in row]
   1090                         ncol.add(c)
   1091                         if len(ncol) > 1:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\matrices\matrices.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1087                             else:
   1088                                 c = len(row)
-> 1089                                 flat = [cls._sympify(i) for i in row]
   1090                         ncol.add(c)
   1091                         if len(ncol) > 1:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\sympify.py in sympify(a, locals, convert_xor, strict, rational, evaluate)
    404     try:
    405         a = a.replace('\n', '')
--> 406         expr = parse_expr(a, local_dict=locals, transformations=transformations, evaluate=evaluate)
    407     except (TokenError, SyntaxError) as exc:
    408         raise SympifyError('could not parse %r' % a, exc)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\parsing\sympy_parser.py in parse_expr(s, local_dict, transformations, global_dict, evaluate)
   1006         code = compile(evaluateFalse(code), '<string>', 'eval')
   1007 
-> 1008     return eval_expr(code, local_dict, global_dict)
   1009 
   1010 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\parsing\sympy_parser.py in eval_expr(code, local_dict, global_dict)
    900     Generally, ``parse_expr`` should be used.
    901     """
--> 902     expr = eval(
    903         code, global_dict, local_dict)  # take local objects in preference
    904 

<string> in <module>

TypeError: 'Symbol' object is not subscriptable
```

I think the error comes from the mix between commas and sympy language, but i can't find a way to solve it.

Any help would be very appreciated
Thank you in advance !

Comment: Where do you define `J`?  From the full error it looks like it's trying to parse `T`, which is the string "'J[0,:],J[i,:]'"

Comment: i've edited my code @hpaulj

Comment: Can't you show some intermediate results, like `J`?  I can't run that code in my head!

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry but i can't find a way to post the output matrices.. Can you help me or is there some documentation explaining how to ?

Comment: I run `sympy` in a `isympy` session, which gives relatively pretty displays.  Then I just use copy-n-paste.  I haven't paid much attention to other `sympy` display controls.

Answer (score 1):

In a `isympy` session, the first `J` is:

```
In [12]: J
Out[12]: 
⎡0  c₀₁  c₀₂  c₀₃  c₀₄⎤
⎢                     ⎥
⎢0   0   c₁₂  c₁₃  c₁₄⎥
⎢                     ⎥
⎢0   0    0   c₂₃  c₂₄⎥
⎢                     ⎥
⎢0   0    0    0   c₃₄⎥
⎢                     ⎥
⎣0   0    0    0    0 ⎦
```

The second just 0s out the first row.

Then:

```
In [15]: i = 1
    ...: T = ('J[0,:]')
    ...: while i < 5:
    ...:     s = (",J[i,:]")
    ...:     T = T + s
    ...:     i = i + 1
    ...: 
In [16]: T
Out[16]: 'J[0,:],J[i,:],J[i,:],J[i,:],J[i,:]'
```

But `sympify(T)` gives the `TypeError: 'Symbol' object is not subscriptable`

But a simple list comprehension produces:

```
In [26]: Matrix([[J[i,:] for i in range(0,5)]])
Out[26]: [0  0  0  0  0  0  0  c₁₂  c₁₃  c₁₄  0  0  0  c₂₃  c₂₄  0  0  0  0  c₃₄  0  0  0  0  0]
```

While `sympy` can `sympify` strings, I don't think it's good idea to use that when other tools are available such a Python lists.

```
In [27]: [J[i,:] for i in range(0,5)]
Out[27]: 
[[0  0  0  0  0], [0  0  c₁₂  c₁₃  c₁₄], [0  0  0  c₂₃  c₂₄], [0  0  0  0  c₃₄], [0  0  0  0 
 0]]
```

Or `sympy` operations like matrix `reshape`:

```
In [29]: J.reshape(1,25)
Out[29]: [0  0  0  0  0  0  0  c₁₂  c₁₃  c₁₄  0  0  0  c₂₃  c₂₄  0  0  0  0  c₃₄  0  0  0  0  0]
```

---

Looks like

```
sympify('J[0,:]')
```

is the problem.  I suspect it "sees" the `J` and makes it a `symbol`, without "knowledge" that you already created a `J` matrix object.

`eval` does work:

```
In [38]: eval('J[0,:],J[1,:]')
Out[38]: ([0  0  0  0  0], [0  0  c₁₂  c₁₃  c₁₄])
```

Also note in `Out[16]` the repeated `[i,:]`.  That string construction does not perform integer replacement.  When faced with debugging problems, examine intermediate steps. It's the details that matter.

Comment: Thank you very much, you solved my problem. It works perfectly in my code ! Could you explain me  the difference between "Matrix([[J[i,:] for i in range(0,5)]])" and "[J[i,:] for i in range(0,5)]" ?

Comment: One is the "raw" list, the other passes it to the `Matrix` constructor.  This is Python.  Argument are evaluated before they are passed to functions.

Comment: Ok i see, thank you very much for your help